# How to create a slider with a non-linear scale?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a slider with a minimum value of 0 and maximum of 500.

I want to when the slider goes to 100, the thumb be in the middle of the slider.

I know it seems wierd, but some programs do it with zoom slider, and I believe it's better.

Comment: see Sam Hocevar's answer for the correct way to do this. The accepted answer is definitively the wrong way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was such an interesting question that I couldn't leave it alone, and hopefully I got what you're asking right :)

You want to change the `Value` of a `Slider` from Linear to a Quadratic Function by specifying the Y value of the function when the Thumb is in the middle.

A Quadratic Function is written on the form
[image: formula]

Since we have 3 points, we have 3 sets of values for X and Y.

```
(X1, Y1) = 0, 0  
(X2, Y2) = MiddleX, CenterQuadraticValue (in your case 100)  
(X3, Y3) = Maximum, Maximum (in your case 500)
```

From here, we can create a Quadratic Equation ([see this link for example](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_find_quadratic_curve.html)) which comes out to
[image: formula]

*Unfortunately, some values in this graph ends up below 0 so they will have to be coerced to 0 (I included a graph in the bottom of the answer).*

I created a control, `QuadraticSlider`, which derives from `Slider` and adds two Dependency Properties: `QuadraticValue` and `CenterQuadraticValue`. It calculates `QuadraticValue` using the formula above based on `Value`, `Maximum`, `Minimum` and `CenterQuadraticValue`. It also does the reverse: setting `QuadraticValue` updates `Value`. So instead of Binding to `Value`, bind to `QuadraticValue`.

**Edit:** The last version was a little buggy. Fixed a couple of things

- Calculating `Value` from `QuadraticValue` no longer breaks when "a" is 0
- Used wrong root from the second degree solution when the derivate was negative

I uploaded a sample application where `QuadraticSlider` is used to zoom a picture. All parameteres can be specified and the first picture uses `Value` and the other `QuadraticValue`.

[Download it here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/QuadraticSliderTest.zip) if you want to try it out.

It looks like this
[image]

*And this is what the graph looks like, notice the values below 0*

[image]

Comment: Good job Meleak! It has some bugs, so I had to edit a few your code to work. For example: In your example, try to change the minimum to 25. Thank you.

Comment: @Seva: I'm unable to find that bug. If you set `Maximum` to 25, you have to set `CenterQuadraticValue` to something below 25, like 10. Otherwise you'll get a pretty buggy behavior but that's because you specified bad parameters :) Also, you'll have to compensate on the `ScaleTransform` on the Images since they start of with a value of 0.002 which I just hardcoded :) (Or did you find something that I overlooked?)

Comment: @Seva: Aha, setting Minimum to 25 does indeed not work as expected. Missread your comment. I'll look into it

Comment: @Seva: I uploaded a new version which fixes some bugs. Tested it for a while and it seems to be working ok this time :)

Comment: Meleak, unfortunately there still a bug :D
I can't define my quadratic value. In XAML code, no matter what I set quadraticValue, it doesn't change. Thanks.

Comment: @Meleak how would I adapt this to work with much larger scales? Say 1 - 1 million? The quadratic value is 1002382 (over 1 million) when the value is 995985 (just under 1 million) then shrinks back to 1 million when the value is 1 million.

Comment: My pragmatic approach would have been to simply use 400*x^2, but I see a use case for your solution ofcourse. ;)

Comment: NO, NO, NO AND NO! Downvoting this to infinity! That's probably the worst possible way to do it! You must use a strictly monotonous function.

Comment: @SamHocevar: +1 for an, by the looks of it, much better answer. -1 for screaming and uncalled for attitude

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 54):

A good formula for the displayed value is a monotonous function such as a power curve, in the following form:

```
DisplayValue = A + B * Math.Exp(C * SliderValue);
```

The internal slider value (from 0 to 1 for instance) is obtained by inverting the formula:

```
SliderValue = Math.Log((DisplayValue - A) / B) / C;
```

Now how to obtain A, B and C? By using the three constraints you gave:

```
f(0.0) = 0
f(0.5) = 100
f(1.0) = 500
```

Three equations, three unknowns, this is solved using basic maths:

```
A + B = 0
A + B exp(C * 0.5) = 100
A + B exp(C) = 500

B (exp(C * 0.5) - 1) = 100
B (exp(C) - 1) = 500

exp(C) - 5 exp(C * 0.5) + 4 = 0  // this is a quadratic equation

exp(C * 0.5) = 4

C = log(16)
B = 100/3
A = -100/3
```

Yielding the following code:

```
double B = 100.0 / 3;
double C = Math.Log(16.0);
DisplayValue = B * (Math.Exp(C * SliderValue) - 1.0);
```

You can see that the display value is at 100 when the internal value is in the middle:

[image: final curve]

**Edit**: since a generic formula was requested, here it is. Given:

```
f(0.0) = x
f(0.5) = y
f(1.0) = z
```

The values for A, B and C are:

```
A = (xz - y²) / (x - 2y + z)
B = (y - x)² / (x - 2y + z)
C = 2 * log((z-y) / (y-x))
```

Note that if `x - 2y + z` or `y - x` is zero, there is no solution and you’ll get a division by zero. That’s because in this case, the scale is actually linear. You need to take care of that special case.

Comment: Very helpful! Is it possible to solve for A, B, C generically, i.e. using variables x, y, z instead of fixed values 0, 100, 500?

Comment: I will second Eugene's request for a generic formula

Comment: I added the generic formula. I omitted all the steps because that would have made the answer really too verbose.

Comment: For those playing at home, remember that Math.Exp and Math.Log are base e, so use the Natural Log in the formula for C = 2*ln((z-y)/(y-x)), especially if you are calculating the constants A, B & C outside of code.

Comment: Is this technique reversible, as would be required for a two-way `IValueConverter`? That is, is there a deterministic way to recover the (unique?) `SliderValue` given the `DisplayValue`? If so, would it be possible for you to illustrate the requisite companion formulae to your helpful generalized solution?

Comment: I think the first two formulae at the beginning of the post are exactly what you are looking for! :-)

Answer (score 13):

let the slider as it is and use a ValueConverter for your bindings. In the ValueConverter use the non-linear scaling to scale the value as you wish.

Comment: I don't think it works. Dosnt valueConverter only format the string of the text?

Comment: no you can create small little pieces of code called ValueConverters - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx, that will convert one value to another during binding .. but nice to give someone a downvote based on his own ignorance - thanks a lot ... pleasure to help you :/

Comment: The other example is a lot of work, but this one is the more correct way to do it.

Comment: dude, how can you change the thumb position inside slider based only in valueconverter?

Comment: you binnd the value to some other value and use a ValueConverter in there so if your internal value is 10 you can have the Converter return 1, 100->2, or whatever. The slider only sees the values after the converter so you can just map linear-scale to log-scale or whatever you want

Comment: Here is a question about how to do the binding itself in C# code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946760/make-a-slider-use-an-existing-ivalueconverter No answer yet.

Comment: Sure the accepted answer is cool, but the `ValueConverter` approach is better.

Comment: I agree, value converter is the best way to do it. If you want to show the current value, you can show the original value in a text box or something, but the slider can be at the converted value, so for example, 100 can be in the middle.

Answer (score 10):

Just as a further reference; if you are not interested on exact positions for your slider to correspond to specific values in your scale but still want a behavior where the slider is more sensitive to values on the beginning of the scale than on the end, then perhaps using a simple log scale may suffice.

```
public class LogScaleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double x = (int)value;
        return Math.Log(x);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double x = (double)value;
        return (int)Math.Exp(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you boxing and unboxing to `int` in both directions? It seems like doing so only serves to constrain the utility of this converter. Wouldn't `double x = System.Convert.ToDouble(value)` be a better choice in both `Convert` and `ConvertBack`?

Comment: I guess that whatever control I was using back in 2012 had an integer property that I wanted to adjust with a log scale. If double works better for you, please go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the algorithm from sam hocevar, here is the code I put together :

```
/// <summary>
/// Scale a linear range between 0.0-1.0 to an exponential scale using the equation returnValue = A + B * Math.Exp(C * inputValue);
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inoutValue">The value to scale</param>
/// <param name="midValue">The value returned for input value of 0.5</param>
/// <param name="maxValue">The value to be returned for input value of 1.0</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private double ExpScale(double inputValue, double midValue, double maxValue)
{
  double returnValue = 0;
  if (inputValue < 0 || inputValue > 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Input value must be between 0 and 1.0");
  if (midValue <= 0 || midValue >= maxValue) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("MidValue must be greater than 0 and less than MaxValue");
  // returnValue = A + B * Math.Exp(C * inputValue);
  double M = maxValue / midValue;
  double C = Math.Log(Math.Pow(M - 1, 2));
  double B = maxValue / (Math.Exp(C) - 1);
  double A = -1 * B;
  returnValue = A + B * Math.Exp(C * inputValue);
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of valid values? When I try `ExpScale(0.1,0.5,1.0)` I'm getting `NAN`

Answer (score 1):

Some addition to Meleak's post.
I've slightly corrected QuadraticSlider. There was issue with event handlers (event on QuadraticValueChanged with yet prevoius value; event during initialization with out of range [min, max] value).

```
protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
{
    QuadraticValue = a * Math.Pow(Value, 2) + b * Value + c;
    base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
}

public double QuadraticValue
{
    get {
        var qv = (double)GetValue(QuadraticValueProperty);
        if (double.IsNaN(qv))
            qv = 0;
        qv = Math.Max(qv, base.Minimum);
        qv = Math.Min(qv, base.Maximum);
        return qv;
    }
    set 
    {
        SetValue(QuadraticValueProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To generalise on Sam Hocevar's excellent answer:

Let the intended Maximum value be M. 
Let the value at the slider midpoint be m. 
(obviously, 0 < m < M), then

```
    A = - M*m^2 / (M^2 - 2*m*M)
    B = M*m^2 / (M^2 - 2*m*M)
    C = Ln((M - m)^2 / m^2) // <- logarithm to the base of e, I always think of 'Log' as base 10
```

One must take care to treat the case 2*m=M seperately, because that leads to a division by 0. But in that case, you'd have the slider behave in a linear fashion anyway.

Chosing m from between M/2 and M makes for a logarithmic curve: The effective slider values rise fast at first, then slowly later on. This basically reverses the effect and gives the user finer control of the higher values.

As mentioned, an m close to M/2 makes the slider basically linear.
Choosing m close to 0 or close to M makes for fine control over the very low or the very high values.

I suppose one could use this in combination with a second slider that sets m to a value between 0 and M to change the ... errr ... sensitive zone of the real slider.

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly as elegant as some of the other answers here but instead of a smooth curve you could just use two straight lines. With y as your slider's position and x as your actual value, you'd use `(y1 - y2)/(x1 - x2)` to get the slope, then `y - y1 = slope * (x - x1)` to get the y intercept. Do that for each half of the slider then use a conditional statement to treat values differently depending on whether they are above or below 50. The basic maths in your case:

```
(0 - 50)/(0 - 100)
-50/-100
1/2
y = x/2
```

...since we know the y intercept is 0. Then...

```
(50-100)/(100-500)
-50/-400
1/8
y - 50 = 1/8 * (x - 100)
y - 50 = x/8 - 25/2
y = x/8 + 75/2
```

From a user experience perspective, you're definitely better off using a curve (I especially like [Cesar's log idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13850984/2199369)) because it avoids a sharp "elbow" where the slider starts suddenly increasing values at a totally different rate. But this approach is simple to implement and flexible (you could easily add more zones with different ratios) so I thought it was worth mentioning it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the go code for deriving the exponential equation: https://play.golang.org/p/JlWlwZjoebE