# Make a slider use an existing IValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, slider, ivalueconverter

I have a [slider](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/blob/master/CmisSync/Windows/PollIntervalSlider.cs) implementing [System.Windows.Controls.Slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
class MySlider : Slider
{
    public MySlider()
    {
        Minimum = 1;
        Maximum = 1000;
    }
}
```

I use it like this: `MySlider slider = new MySlider() { Width = 400, Name = "TheSlider"};`

It works well, but it is linear.
I want to make it **non-linear** because sensible values are like 1, 2, 10, 1000 (for instance).
So I defined a non-linear [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
public class LogScaleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)Math.Log((int)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)Math.Exp((double)value);
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:** How to make the **slider** use this **converter**?

Comment: do you have a viewmodel?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: No, just MySlider as seen in source code above.

Comment: A value converter is typically used in data dinding, not directly in the control. If you need to make it work without data binding, you may just add another property to your MySlider class, e.g. `LogValue`.

Comment: Thanks all for the effort, especially Ill and Andrew. Unfortunately I haven't been able to make your suggestions work, probably because I am new to Microsoft technologies. I ended up merging the logarithmic converter into the slider, really not elegant but at least it works: https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/blob/master/CmisSync/Windows/PollIntervalSlider.cs . Usage: `new PollIntervalSlider(){PollInterval = 5000};`. Sorry I award the bounty based more on your effort than on actual tested result. I will accept most upvoted answer once more votes get casted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: Giving you a full working code.**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <spikes:LogScaleConverter x:Key="LogScaleConverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox x:Name="InputNumberTextBox" Width="100" Text="{Binding InputNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Slider Width="1000"
            Minimum="1" 
            Maximum="100"
            Value="{Binding ElementName=InputNumberTextBox,Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource LogScaleConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**LogScaleConverter.cs**

```
public class LogScaleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var stringValue = value.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue)) return null;

        var intValue = int.Parse(stringValue);
        return Math.Log(intValue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)Math.Exp((double)value);
    }
}
```

Notice now that when you type something in the `textbox` it'll change the value of the slider based on your formula. You can put a break point on the `Convert` and see if that is the value that you really want in the `slider`.

I don't think it is necessary to create a `MySlider` class since you are only setting the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties which is already available on the actual object itself. You should only be extending a control if you are creating custom stuff like defining your own `Dependency Properties`.

Comment: I posted my complete source code, and it does not have "PropertyName". Could you please use variable names from my code, or modify my code to include this variable where it belongs? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The "PropertyName" is just a placeholder. You actually want a property in your class that is bound to the DataContext of the View

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but could you please paste `public int SliderValue { get; set; }` where it belongs in your code? And could you please put the valueBinding code where it belongs? (at the end of the MainClass constructor I presume?). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Did you make it work, or any questions you still have?

Comment: @Ill Please see my comment on the question. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I'll get back to you with a full example when I get time. No worries. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

Make window Resource as

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:LogScaleConverter x:Key="LogScaleConverterInstanse"/>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Make a TextBox(or any element)  `<TextBox x:Name="firstName" />`

Bind your slider to element

```
 <Slider Height="23" Name="slider1" Width="100" Value="{Binding Text,ElementName=      firstName,Converter={StaticResource LogScaleConverterInstanse}}"/>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't use XML definitions, just plain C# code: `MySlider slider = new MySlider() { Width = 400, TheValue = 10 }`

Comment: Okay Use Like this for binding   var slider = new MySlider();
            var bnd = new Binding("Text") { ElementName = "firstName" };
            bnd.Converter = new LogScaleConverter();
                 
            slider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, bnd);

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you are having with the answers is that everyone is assuming (correctly in the case of common WPF usage) that your slider's value is being bound to some other control (textbox for example) or a ViewModel property. In this common case, the converter is applied within the binding (see all other answers) and converts the slider's internal linear value to your logarithmic value.

If you are just using this in a basic application where your code-behind or other application code is actually just polling the slider control directly, then you can use your converter as such:

```
var logConverter = new LogScaleConverter();
var logValue = logConverter.Convert(mySlider.Value, typeof(double), null, null);
```

But I have to say that this makes little sense as you could simply use a method or place the conversion in line in your code. Using the converter would only potentially make sense if this is also being used through binding somewhere else in your UI and that converter code might change.

Since you are making a custom control anyway, another approach would be to add a new DependencyProperty to your slider control (maybe call it 'LogSlider.LogValue') that handles this conversion directly:

```
public partial class LogSlider : Slider
{
    public LogSlider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata();
        metadata.PropertyChangedCallback += ValuePropertyChangedCallback;
        ValueProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LogSlider), metadata);
    }

    public double LogValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LogValueProperty);}
        set { SetValue(LogValueProperty, (value));}
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LogValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LogValue", typeof(double), typeof(LogSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, LogValuePropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void LogValuePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(ValueProperty, Math.Exp((double)args.NewValue));
    }

    private static void ValuePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(LogValueProperty, Math.Log((double)args.NewValue));
    }
}
```

Now you can access the LogValue directly from your custom Slider control as well as bind bidirectionally to it in the UI - with changes to the linear value being reflected in the log and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var slider = new MySlider();
    var bnd = new Binding("Text") { ElementName = "firstName" };
    bnd.Converter = new LogScaleConverter();

    slider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, bnd);
```

Comment: What are "Text" and "firstName"? My code above does not contain such variable names.

Comment: firstName is name of TextBox whose Text value slider is binded.

Comment: With `var bnd = new Binding();`: `InvalidOperationException: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath`

Comment: yes u have to bind to a uielement. or u can implement this.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(MySlider_ValueChanged); for slider and use flag so that it call only once at a change