# Imitate Powerpoint slider zoom values in WPF

Tags: wpf, slider

I've been trying to look at the properties of Slider in WPF to imitate the Slider Zoom of Powerpoint, but i can't find a way to imitate it.

In Powerpoint, the Min Value = 10 and Max Value = 400. But the center value is equal to 100.

In Slider in WPF, if Min Value = 10 and Max Value = 400. The center value is not 100. it is evenly distributed. Not like in Powerpoint.

You have any idea on how to imitate the powerpoint zoom slider?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246622/how-to-create-a-slider-with-a-non-linear-scale) is what you're looking for.
Put your slider like this:

```
<Slider Name="mySlider" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="2" Value="1" LargeChange="0.1" SmallChange="0.01" TickPlacement="Both" Ticks="0,0.5,1,1.5,2"/>
```

and e.g. square the `mySlider.Value` to get the desired zoom factor.