# Non linear scale slider (in layman's terms)

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to create a non-linear slider and found the following post.

The 2 expressions illustrated look like what I need but I don't what A,B,andC are?

Here's the [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102320/139698)

I understand there's an input, mid point, and max so I thought that's what A,B,and C were. One of those variables being the slider value, however, it shows 3 variables with slider value.

It’s like they’re showing how to solve using half code and half math, which is confusing me a little.

[image]

**Update:**

I'm trying to use my own values `(0;1) (50;200,000) (100;1,931,946)` where slider value 0 to 100 with their respective display values. But I'm not sure I went thru formula correctly?

[image]

**Update 2**

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are given three points that the curve must pass through. Given that, you can solve for A, B, and C: if you write down the given equation for each (slider value, display value) pair, then you have three equations in the unknowns A, B, and C. Since it's a nonlinear equation, you can try to rework it into a linear form which is easy to solve, or you might have to solve it numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider slider values as X-coordinate, and display values as Y-coordinate. So you have done three points. A, B, and C are unknowns yet. Substitute X and Y into formula, and you'll get three equations for three unknowns.

Example: you have slider values 0, 50, and 100 and corresponding diplay values 1, 3, 10, so points are `(0; 1), (5; 3), (10, 10)`

```
1 = A + B * exp(C * 0)   
3 = A + B * exp(C * 5)
10 = A + B * exp(C * 10)
```

From the first equation (because `exp(0)==1`):

```
A = 1 - B
```

so

```
3 = 1 - B + B * exp(C * 5)
10 = 1 - B + B * exp(C * 10)
```

Subtitute `t = exp(C * 5)`, so

```
2 = B * (t - 1)
9 = B * (t^2 - 1)
```

Divide the second by the the first

```
4.5 = t + 1
t = 3.5
exp(C * 5) = 3.5
C = ln(3.5) / 5 ~= 0.25
```

Now for B and A:

```
2 = B * 2.5
B = 2 / 2.5 ~= 0.8
A = 1 - B = 0.2
```

Check for middle and one more point (slider=7):

```
0.2 + 0.8 * exp(0.25 * 5) = 2.992 
0.2 + 0.8 * exp(0.25 * 7) = 4.80
```

(note that having zero point and `max=2*mid` makes calculations rather simple)

Example Python implementation ([look at ideone](https://ideone.com/0Ry7mR))

```
import math

def params(x_range, y0, y1, y2):  #y1 in the middle
    t = (y2 - y0) / (y1 - y0) - 1
    c = math.log(t) * 2 / x_range
    b = (y1 - y0) / (t - 1)
    a = 1 - b
    return a, b, c

def formula(x,a,b,c):
    return(a + b * math.exp(x * c))

a,b,c = params(100, 1, 200000, 1931946)
print(a, b, c)

for i in range(0, 101, 5):
    print(i, formula(i, a, b, c))

-26109.302772223844 26110.302772223844 0.043173770885434115
0 1.0
10 14098.765851726315
20 35808.35465870108
30 69239.62675705353
40 120721.4841082625
50 199999.99999999994
60 322083.45629645145
70 510083.57377646235
80 799590.8112409151
90 1245412.0249069682
100 1931945.9999999988
```

Comment: What does exp mean?

Comment: Exponent function e^x  ("in mathematics..." line [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)) (Math.Exp at your picture)

Comment: And ln is log? When I calculate log(3.5)/5 on calculator it says ~=.10?    https://pasteboard.co/KdnfTC3.jpg

Comment: `ln` is natural logarithm, `Math.Log` in c# (by e basis, not by 10 ). If you use Windows calculator in engineer mode, `log` button works as log10, but  there is also `ln` button (in Android calc too)

Comment: How did you get t+1 in 4.5 = t+1?

Comment: t^2-1 = (t-1)*(t+1), so when we divide this expression by (t-1), we get (t+1)

Comment: updated original post with values I'm trying to use but not sure if correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. More exact values A=-26110, B=26111, C=0.04317 give 199963 for the middle point (if we will use precise values, error will be smaller)

Comment: I added a 2nd update to OP, are the numbers I'm getting to be expected when you go back and forth between slider and display? I would think it would be closer to 50 for slider. Just curious, not an issue, just want to learn.

Comment: @Rod Rounding errors during manual calculation do influence on result precision. Look at the code (plain Python, should be very close to c#)